# Unexpected behavior of append() method. Why, when adding a dictionary to the list, are the previous elements of the list overwritten?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, append

The following code checks the presence of the company name (from ***tickerList***) or its fragment in the text of the news (from **newsList**).
In the case when the company is found in the **news** *print* gives out the expected ticker of the company, but after adding this news to the list, something nonsense happens :(
It's looks like, when appending a dictionary (**news**) to the list (**tickersNews**), are the previous elements of the list overwritten. Why?

It should be noted that when news appending as a dictionary converted to a string, everything works as it should

```
import re

tickersList = [('ATI', 'Allegheny rporated', 'Allegheny Technologies Incorporated'), ('ATIS', 'Attis', 'Attis Industries, Inc.'), ('ATKR', 'Atkore International Group', 'Atkore International Group Inc.'), ('ATMP', 'Barclays + Select M', 'Barclays ETN+ Select MLP'), ('ATNM', 'Actinium', 'Actinium Pharmaceuticals, Inc.'), ('ATNX', 'Athenex', 'Athenex, Inc.'), ('ATOS', 'Atossa Genetics', 'Atossa Genetics Inc.'), ('ATRA', 'Atara Biotherapeutics', 'Atara Biotherapeutics, Inc.'), ('ATRC', 'AtriCure', 'AtriCure, Inc.'), ('ATRO', 'Astronics', 'Astronics Corporation'), ('ATRS', 'Antares Pharma', 'Antares Pharma, Inc.'), ('ATSG', 'Air Transport Services Group', 'Air Transport Services Group, Inc.'),  ('CJ', 'C&J Energy', 'C&J Energy Services, Inc.'), ('CJJD', 'China Jo-Jo Drugstores', 'China Jo-Jo Drugstores, Inc.'), ('CLAR', 'Clarus', 'Clarus Corporation'), ('CLD', 'Cloud Peak Energy', 'Cloud Peak Energy Inc.'), ('CLDC', 'China Lending', 'China Lending Corporation'), ('CLDR', 'Cloudera', 'Cloudera, Inc.')]

newsList = [
    {'title':'Atara Biotherapeutics Announces Planned Chief Executive Officer Transition'},
    {'title':'Chongqing Jingdong Pharmaceutical and Athenex Announce a Strategic Partnership and Licensing Agreement to Develop and Commercialize KX2-391 in China'}
           ]

tickersNews = []

for news in newsList:
    # pass through the list of companies looking for their mention in the news
    for ticker, company, company_full in tickersList:
        # clear the full name of the company from brackets, spaces, articles,
        # points and commas and save fragments of the full name to the list
        companyFullFragments = company_full.replace(',', '')\
            .replace('.', '').replace('The ', ' ')\
            .replace('(', ' ').replace(')', ' ')\
            .replace('  ', ' ').strip().split()
        # looking for a company in the news every time cutting off
        # the last fragment from the full company name
        for i in range(len(companyFullFragments), 0, -1):
            companyFullFragmentsString = ' '.join(companyFullFragments[:i]).strip()
            lookFor_company = r'(^|\s){0}(\s|$)'.format(companyFullFragmentsString)
            results_company = re.findall(lookFor_company, news['title'])
            # if the title of the news contains the name of the company,
            # then we add the ticker, the found fragment and the full name
            # of the company to the news, print the news and add it to the list
            if results_company:
                news['ticker'] = ticker#, companyFullFragmentsString, company_full
                print(news['ticker'], 'found')
                #tickersNews.append(str(news))
                #-----------------------------Here is the problem!(?)
                tickersNews.append(news)
                # move on to the next company
                break

print(20*'-', 'appended:')
for news in tickersNews:
    print(news['ticker'])
```

Output (list of dict):

```
ATRA found
ATNX found
CJJD found
CLDC found
-------------------- appended:
ATRA
CLDC
CLDC
CLDC
```

Output (list of strings):

```
ATRA found
ATNX found
CJJD found
CLDC found
-------------------- appended as a strings:
["{'title': 'Atara Biotherapeutics Announces Planned Chief Executive Officer Transition', 'ticker': 'ATRA'}", "{'title': 'Chongqing Jingdong Pharmaceutical and Athenex Announce a Strategic Partnership and Licensing Agreement to Develop and Commercialize KX2-391 in China', 'ticker': 'ATNX'}", "{'title': 'Chongqing Jingdong Pharmaceutical and Athenex Announce a Strategic Partnership and Licensing Agreement to Develop and Commercialize KX2-391 in China', 'ticker': 'CJJD'}", "{'title': 'Chongqing Jingdong Pharmaceutical and Athenex Announce a Strategic Partnership and Licensing Agreement to Develop and Commercialize KX2-391 in China', 'ticker': 'CLDC'}"]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem originates from 2 lines: `news['ticker'] = ticker` and `tickersNews.append(news)` which are located inside for loop. Much simpler version of your problem is:

```
a = 10
a = 20
a = 30
print(a, a, a)
```

Output will be `30 30 30`. I guess it's obvious.

To solve the problem you may use several approaches.

**First possibility** (easiest). Replace `tickersNews.append(news)` with `tickersNews.append(news.copy())`.

**Second possibility** (preferable). Don't use `tickersNews`. For every `news` create empty list `news['ticker_list'] = list()`. For every `ticker` append it to `news['ticker_list']`:

```
import re

tickersList = [('ATI', 'Allegheny rporated', 'Allegheny Technologies Incorporated'), ('ATIS', 'Attis', 'Attis Industries, Inc.'), ('ATKR', 'Atkore International Group', 'Atkore International Group Inc.'), ('ATMP', 'Barclays + Select M', 'Barclays ETN+ Select MLP'), ('ATNM', 'Actinium', 'Actinium Pharmaceuticals, Inc.'), ('ATNX', 'Athenex', 'Athenex, Inc.'), ('ATOS', 'Atossa Genetics', 'Atossa Genetics Inc.'), ('ATRA', 'Atara Biotherapeutics', 'Atara Biotherapeutics, Inc.'), ('ATRC', 'AtriCure', 'AtriCure, Inc.'), ('ATRO', 'Astronics', 'Astronics Corporation'), ('ATRS', 'Antares Pharma', 'Antares Pharma, Inc.'), ('ATSG', 'Air Transport Services Group', 'Air Transport Services Group, Inc.'),  ('CJ', 'C&J Energy', 'C&J Energy Services, Inc.'), ('CJJD', 'China Jo-Jo Drugstores', 'China Jo-Jo Drugstores, Inc.'), ('CLAR', 'Clarus', 'Clarus Corporation'), ('CLD', 'Cloud Peak Energy', 'Cloud Peak Energy Inc.'), ('CLDC', 'China Lending', 'China Lending Corporation'), ('CLDR', 'Cloudera', 'Cloudera, Inc.')]

newsList = [
    {'title':'Atara Biotherapeutics Announces Planned Chief Executive Officer Transition'},
    {'title':'Chongqing Jingdong Pharmaceutical and Athenex Announce a Strategic Partnership and Licensing Agreement to Develop and Commercialize KX2-391 in China'}
           ]

for news in newsList:
    news['ticker_list'] = list()
    for ticker, company, company_full in tickersList:
        companyFullFragments = company_full.replace(',', '')\
            .replace('.', '').replace('The ', ' ')\
            .replace('(', ' ').replace(')', ' ')\
            .replace('  ', ' ').strip().split()
        for i in range(len(companyFullFragments), 0, -1):
            companyFullFragmentsString = ' '.join(companyFullFragments[:i]).strip()
            lookFor_company = r'(^|\s){0}(\s|$)'.format(companyFullFragmentsString)
            results_company = re.findall(lookFor_company, news['title'])
            if results_company:
                news['ticker_list'].append(ticker)
                # print(ticker, 'found')
                break

print('tickers for news:')

for news in newsList:
    print(news['ticker_list'])
```

Output will be:

```
tickers for news:
['ATRA']
['ATNX', 'CJJD', 'CLDC']
```